# Maintain Number of ViewCount for the Video files

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I need help on the schema changes. I have a video table storing videos and I wanted to know the actual `ViewCount` for the videos.

Here is the Video table schema that I have now:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.VideoFiles(
VideoId     int IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
VideoTitle  nvarchar(64) NOT NULL,
VideoDescription nvarchar(2048),
PublishDate date,
Duration    time,
VideoUrl    nvarchar(256),
--ViewCount bigint,
UpdateTime  datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )
```

I can have a `ViewCount` column which will be increased by +1 on every launch of the video file, which looks like the simple way. But how can I manage uniqueness in the video view?

```
User1 view Video1 = Video1 Count =>1  
User2 view Video1 = Video1 Count =>2  
User1 view Video2 = Video2 Count =>1  
User1 view Video1 = Video1 Count =>2 (not increased as he already seen this video)
```

Thanks,
Prabhat

Comment: You will need a Table like  VideoId/UserID/FirstSeenDate 1:N with unique key on VideoId/UserID

Comment: Thanks @bummi for the hint and `FirstSeendate` column suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required Structure could look like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ViedeoViews](
    [VideoID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ViedeoViews] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [VideoID] ASC,
    [UserID] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ViedeoViews]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ViedeoViews_VideoFiles] FOREIGN KEY([VideoID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[VideoFiles] ([VideoId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ViedeoViews] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ViedeoViews_VideoFiles]
GO



Create View V_VideoFiles as
Select dbo.VideoFiles.*,(Select COUNT(*) from ViedeoViews vv where vv.VideoID=VideoFiles.VideoID) as ViewCount
from VideoFiles
```

Comment: Thanks @bummi for your solution with the view. What will happen if I want to extend the view to external users? Can I still maintain the Uniqueness like YouTube?

Comment: If the user can be identified you can add him to the ViedeoView, if not an field ViewCountUnIdentified  in your maintable could be used Count would be ViewCountUnIdentified + (Subselect).

Comment: Thanks @bummi and yes the view by public cant not be identified at thos moment until we have Ip Tracking (at minimum, I think). So the `ViewCountUnIdentified` column in `VideoFiles` table will help I think?

Answer (score 1):

Create a table

```
UserId int/UniqueIdentifier
VideoId Int
TimeOfView Datetime
SessionId int/UniqueIdentifier
```

This will help you.You will be able to give every answer from the business point. Like total view, view/day or unique visits/day. Similarly for week,months and year. More attributes can also be added for  UserVisit.

Comment: Nice and quick solution @Ravi. Thanks for this.  So here I can find the unique view for the Application users.  What will happen if I want to extend the view to external users? Can I still maintain the Uniqueness like YouTube?

Comment: @Prabhat : You can log them as ANONYMOUS user. You can add `SessionNumber/Id int/UniqueIdentifier` as a column. You can atleast track views for that session.

Comment: Yes @Ravi, I think you have a good point here but How can I separate users and session ids (I think this will not be `int`) when my `Userid` are `int` type.

Comment: Thanks @Ravi for the clarification. Now I see what you mean. I tried to make both the answers are Accepted Answer, but I cant do that also I have less reputations to make vote/point to these answers.